# "Unable to connect to the MKS: Too many socket connect attempts" when trying to launch a virtual machine in VMware Workstation Pro 14.1.1

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation, sockets

I am  trying to launch a virtual machine in VMware Workstation Pro 14.1.1. Host: Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. Guest: Microsoft Windows 10. I get the error message "Unable to connect to the MKS: Too many socket connect attempts". What could be the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that the VMware Workstation UI (normally an unprivileged `vmware.exe` process) cannot connect to the MKS (normally run as part of the privileged `vmware-vmx.exe` process). (The MKS is the component responsible for handling mouse and keyboard input to the guest and for drawing the guest's virtual screen.)

The unprivileged `vmware.exe` process cannot spawn a privileged `vmware-vmx.exe` process itself.  The service that spawns the `vmware-vmx.exe` process and that mediates communication with it (such as connecting to the MKS) is the VMware Authorization Service (`vmware-authd.exe`).  Unless you run VMware Workstation as an elevated administrator (not recommended), it is required to run VMs, so that service *must* be running (Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services > VMware Authorization Service).  When VMware Workstation is installed, the VMware Authorization Service is configured to start automatically.  Don't change it.

Some other VMware services depend on the VMware Authorization Service, so starting those other ones would have the effect of fixing the problem.  However, the proper, fundamental fix is to keep the VMware Authorization Service running.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the error as follows: Open "Services" Console via `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools\Services`, OR press <kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to open run prompt and type `services.msc`. Search for the service `VMware Workstation Server` and start it:

[image]

Comment: In this case wouldn't we have to start the service *everytime* we get the problem? Could we set Startup type to `automatic`?

Comment: @SaaranshGarg thanks, yes, that's indeed an option.

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense.  Did the error occur only when attempting to connect to "shared" virtual machines?  If not, then the "VMware Workstation Server" service would not be involved at all.  Also, the simpler way to start this service is, within VMware Workstation Pro, to go to Edit > Preferences > Shared VMs and to enable sharing.

Comment: @jamesdlin the error occurred when trying to launch a virtual machine in VMware Workstation Pro 14.1.1. Everything local on my computer.

Comment: "Shared" VMs run on your computer too (but are accessible remotely).  If you're not using shared VMs, then the vmware-hostd service (which manages shared VMs) shouldn't be related to that error.

Comment: Now, the answer that I *would* believe is that starting the VMware Authorization Service (vmware-authd) would solve your problem.  That service should be set to Automatic and *must* be running if you don't run VMware Workstation Pro as an elevated administrator.

Comment: @jamesdlin Thanks, this wasn't a shared VM.  Good catch, it seems that starting the service `VMware Workstation Server` caused the  VMware Authorization Service to start as well. I may have gotten lucky with this side effect :)